# Set index for aggregated dataframe

Tags: pandas

I did some calculation to a list of dataframes. I'd like the result dataframe uses `rangeindex`. However, it uses one of the column name as index, even I set `index=None`

```
d1 = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'is_free': [True, False, False, True, True], 'level': ['Top', 'Mid', 'Top', 'Top', 'Low']}
d2 = {'id': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], 'is_free': [True, True, False, False, False], 'level': ['Top', 'High', 'Top', 'Top', 'Low']}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df_list = [d1, d2]

dfs = []
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df = df.groupby('is_free')['id'].count()
    dfs.append(df)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=dfs, index=None)
```

It returns

```
is_free False   True
id      2       3
id      3       2
```

df.index returns

```
Index(['id', 'id'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=dfs, index=None).reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, in general, I would avoid `append` iteratively. Try `concat`:

```
pd.concat({i:d.groupby('is_free')['id'].count() 
           for i,d in enumerate(df_list)}, 
          axis=1).T
```

Or use `pd.DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame({i:d.groupby('is_free')['id'].count() 
           for i,d in enumerate(df_list)}).T
```

Output:

```
is_free  False  True 
0            2      3
1            3      2
```